# Form designer differs for custom form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I'm new to .net and I am developing my library dll testing it against a test application for gaining experience etc.... I apologize in advance if I am not using the correct terms in my message.

As I want to add some custom properties to all my future forms I created a custom form with some extra properties.

I then create a form based on the new custom form and compared the .designer.vb files. I found that changing inherits system.windows.forms.form to inherits library.Myform should do it but I also found another difference:

Both designer files contain code to dispose components however they are slightly different:
designer generated for form based on system.windows.forms.form:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub
```

the one for the form based on library.Myform:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
        components.Dispose()
    End If
    MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
End Sub
```

Why that difference and should I modify my forms created from the custom form so that they contain the Try-Finally block. If yes is there a way to change the behavior of vs to do it when creating the form based on the custom form.